# Adding active class to directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I'm trying to use jQuery to add an `.active` class to my Bootstrap navigation links. I'm using some simple code I found elsewhere but have had to modify it.

I want the `.active` class to be added to the relevant `.nav-link` when on any page in the relevant directory, e.g. to be added to the Photography link in the nav bar whether a user is on the */photography* page or */photography/fashion* page.

This is what I have so far;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var urlFull = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var urlFirst = '/' + urlFull[1];

$('.navbar-nav .nav-link').each(function() {
    if (this.href === urlFirst) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
});
```

I'm pretty sure my issue is to do with the `if` statement, but I'm pretty new to Javascript and I can't see the problem! I've used console.log to check my variables and they correspond with the links set in the navigation.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Check the boolean result of this.href === urlFirst.

Comment: It returns as false

Comment: Ah I see, I've changed `this.href` to `this.pathname` and it seems to be working correctly, I think! Thanks for your help Jeroen, it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

It looks like my issue was with `this.href` when it should have been `this.pathname`. It seems to be working correctly now, but time will tell when I've built more pages!